# Change dpi of an image from 72 to 96 using php

Tags: php, gd

i want to change dpi of an image from 72 to 96 using GD or php.

thanks in advance..

Comment: Of an existing or blank image?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what you're asking. When you display an image on a 72 DPI monitor, it's 72 DPI. When you display it on a 96 DPI monitor, it's 96. Images do not have a native DPI, they have a pixel size. DPI is determined by the display medium.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "I'm not sure I understand..."

Comment: @itchy: OP is talking about "recommended" DPI which is (often) saved with the image so that printers, converters and similar know which DPI to use when printing / displaying the image (if they wish to use this information of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can set resolution with PHP iMagick:

```
public function setDPI($DPIX, $DPIY) {

    $this->image->setImageResolution($DPIX,$DPIY);

}
```